# Can I print two acronym lists with different layouts with the acro package?

Tags: enumitem, acro

This question is the equivalent to the 'Hail Mary pass' in American football! I'm trying to use the `acro` package to do something which it wasn't designed to do, so I'm probably going to luck out – but 'nothing ventured' as they say.

The `acro` package allows you to print different lists of acronyms for different defined classes – for example, I have the classes 'genes' and 'other acronyms'.  So far so good.  However, I thought I'd try to use the package to produce a list of suppliers (names and addresses), so I have created a class 'supplier', use a supplier short name in place of an acronym, and print out a separate list for this class.  The problem is that I need to format the list differently, as supplier names (even short ones) tend to have rather more characters than your average acronym.  I can define a list layout using the `enumitem` package, so I have defined lists 'acronyms' and 'suppliers'.  However, the `\printacronyms` command always uses the 'acronyms' list format.  What I really need is to create a command which is essentially the same as the \printacronyms command (eg `\printsuppliers`) which uses the 'suppliers' list format.  I have no idea if this is even possible, but I know that there are some smart guys on this forum!  I can't think of a suitable MWE on this occasion, the question is more general than specific.

Comment: hmmm.  in u.s. lingo (at least the northeastern u.s.), "luck out" means that one had good luck and the hoped-for outcome ensued.  is this a difference between british and u.s. usage?

Comment: I think it can be used either way this side of the pond, the meaning should be clear from the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make make `acro` use any valid list type by saying

```
\acsetup{list-type=<name of list>}
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{acro,enumitem}

\newlist{foo}{description}{1}
\newlist{baz}{description}{1}
\setlist[foo]{font=\normalfont\itshape}
\setlist[baz]{font=\normalfont\scshape}

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short = foo ,
  long  = the description of foo ,
  class = foo
}
\DeclareAcronym{baz}{
  short = baz ,
  long  = the description of baz ,
  class = baz
}

\begin{document}

\ac{foo} \ac{baz}

\acsetup{list-type=foo}
\printacronyms[name=Foo types,include-classes=foo]

\acsetup{list-type=baz}
\printacronyms[name=Baz types,include-classes=baz]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted – I can't believe that I've spent the entire morning reading the acro documentation and missed it!